# Set exec sp_executesql variable

Tags: sql-server

Not SET variable @Set. This return null or SQL return error.

```
declare @Field as varchar(10); 
declare @Set as varchar(10); 
set @Field = 'id_fonte' 

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select ' + @Set + ' = id_fonte 
              from fontes
             where [' + replace(@Field, '''', '''''') + '] = 54';

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expect this snippet to do as it stands currently? You haven’t set an explicit value for `@Set`; what do you expect it to evaluate to?

Comment: You cann't reference a variable declared in the calling script from the command executed with `sp_executesql`. See docs how to pass and return a value with the second+ parameters of `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues here.  First, the variable @set has not been given a value, therefore it is NULL.  Anytime you use the + operator to do string concatenation, any string + NULL will equal NULL.  Thus your @sql variable will be set to NULL.  You can see this by changing one your lines as follows:

```
declare @Set as varchar(10) = '';
```

Nevertheless, the syntax of the statement stored in the @sql command looks suspect.  Add the line

```
PRINT @sql
```

before the execution during testing to see the exact syntax of the command that you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OUTPUT` parameter with `sp_executesql`, like this:

> Note correct use of `QUOTENAME` to escape the column name.

```sql
declare @Field as varchar(10) = 'id_fonte'; 
declare @Set as varchar(10); 

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select @Set = id_fonte
from fontes
where ' + QUOTENAME(@Field) + ' = 54;
';

print @sql; -- for testing

exec sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@Set varchar(10) OUTPUT',
  @Set = @Set OUTPUT;
```